# Rally AppSDK: Is there a way to facilitate "Inter-Panel" communication between Apps in the new layout schema

Tags: rally

So I'm just getting used to and getting my arms around the new "panel-based" App scheme released with the 5/5/2012 version of Rally. At first it was a bit frustrating to lose the window real estate when I've been accustomed to full-page iFrames.

I am curious however - from a desire to optimize the way I use real estate onscreen for an App page - I would like to setup and utilize a multi-panel App whose components can communicate. For instance, I'd like to have one App panel display some control widgets and perhaps an AppSDK table, and a second App panel display a chart or grid that responds to events/controls in the first panel.

I've been scanning the AppSDK docs for hints as to how this might be accomplished, but I'm coming up short. Is there a way to wire up event listeners in one App panel that respond to widget controls in another?

Comment: This has been implemented in the recently released 2.0rc1 version of the SDK: https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/messaging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have not decided the best way to have the Apps communicate yet. That is something we are still spiking out internally to find the best way to do it.

Each custom App is in an IFrame so figuring out how to make them communicate can be a bit tricky. Once we figure out a good way to do it we will be sure to let you know.

Comment: Thank you for this update. Out of curiosity - when I do a view page source on any of the new App Pages (i.e. the container for the new Apps or App Panels), it looks like Apps (including AppSDK 1.0 apps)_ are now frames within a whole mix of complex ExtJS. Can I infer from the "Ext-ness" of the whole framework, that inter-panel communication will be coming only for AppSDK 2.0 Apps? Any chance this will be implemented for AppSDK 1.0 apps?

Comment: I would not expect any Rally created functionality to be added to SDK 1.0. We are going full speed to make the new SDK so powerful that we never have to look back.

Answer (score 0):

Has this topic, "app Communication", been addressed yet?  I would to have one Custom Grid show User Stories.  When a user story is selected another grid show the related tasks.