# Cross App Messaging in SDK 2.0

Tags: rally

Can I have one or more Apps respond to and event in another App in SDK 2.0?

For example, say I have one App in a dashboard that allows the user to select something.  Can I (and how would I) have other Apps installed in that same dashboard respond to that event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been implemented in the recently released 2.0rc1 version of the SDK:

https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/messaging

Answer (score 1):

Per [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922367/charles-ferentchak) answer to:

[Rally AppSDK: Is there a way to facilitate “Inter-Panel” communication between Apps in the new layout schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491605/rally-appsdk-is-there-a-way-to-facilitate-inter-panel-communication-between-a)

This hasn't been implemented yet - Rally's engineering team is spiking on this and other aspects of getting AppSDK 2.0 more feature-complete.